# ibm_db_dbi connent to DB2 executing a sql statement

Tags: python, db2

`Python3.5` is normal, but `Python2.7` raises this below error

> ibm_db_dbi.Error:ibm_db_dbi::Error : Error occurred during processing of statement

Here is my code

```
import ibm_db_dbi

def Conn_DB():
    global cur, conn
    database = "test"
    hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 50000
    user = "test"
    passwd = "test"
    conn = ibm_db_dbi.connect(
    "DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%s;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=%s;PWD=%s" % (database, hostname, port, user, passwd), "",
    "")  
    conn.set_autocommit(True)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return conn, cur

def main():

    Conn_DB()
    global cur
    obj = ["1.1.1.1"]
    fw_ip = ["3.3.3.3"]
    cur.execute("select 1 from TEST where IP='%s' and firewall='%s'" % (obj,fw_ip))
    if cur.fetchone():
         print('hello, world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: There should be more details to the error, please add them.

Comment: **bold**details error message as below:**bold**
File "D:\firewall_prase\test.py",line 25,in main
cur.execute("select 1 from TEST where IP='%s' and firewall='%s'" % (obj,fw_ip))
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.7-py2.7.egg\ibm_db_dbi.py" line 1334,in execute
  self._prepare_helper(operation)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.7-py2.7.egg\ibm_db_dbi.py" line 1205,in _prepare_helper
  raise self.messages[len(self.messages) -1]

ibm_db_dbi.Error:ibm_db_dbi::Error : Error occurred during processing of statement

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are passing one-item lists instead of scalar values in your string interpolation with modulus operator, `%`. Therefore, the length issue is raised which you can see by printing out concatenated SQL string which shows an invalid query with unclosed quotes:

```
print("select 1 from TEST where IP='%s' and firewall='%s'" % (obj, fw_ip))

# select 1 from TEST where IP='['1.1.1.1']' and firewall='['3.3.3.3']'
```

Interestingly, as you point out, this does not fail in Python 3 but does in Python 2. To resolve, simply index first item or assign no brackets `[]` to *obj* and *fw_ip* that renders them a list.

```
obj = ["1.1.1.1"]
fw_ip = ["3.3.3.3"]

cur.execute("select 1 from TEST where IP='%s' and firewall='%s'" % (obj[0], fw_ip[0]))
```

However, in best practices, use parameters with *params* argument of `cur.execute()` which expects a sequence such as tuple or list but adjust SQL string with unquoted placemarkers, `?`:

```
cur.execute("select 1 from TEST where IP = ? and firewall = ?", (obj[0], fw_ip[0]))
```